# PHP web server output variable contain whitespace

Tags: php, http, webserver

Im facing a problem on php web server script. I output(By echo) a variable, with value, 
I.E : "variableA=hello". However, when i get the output at client side(flash or JS), it contain a whitespace in left hand side, so it turn "variableA" into " variableA". This is create a problem that my client side unable to receive the post data by assigning "variableA". I've search all around and i found no solution for me.

coding example:
**server side:**

```
$variableA="hello";    
echo "variableA=".$variableA;    
exit();
```

**client side:**

```
$count = curl_exec($ch);    
echo "RESULT =!".$count."!\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
RESULT =! variableA=hello !;
```

P.S: The "!" is to indicate the begin and ending.

Extra Info: 
when i add some funny thing on the left hand side, and "&" before the "variableA", it work well. I understand that "&" is splitter for HTTP variable.

Comment: it just a simple echo "variableA=hello" , as simple as that.
And when i CURL and print out the result, it show a whitespace in front. I hope the mark down is not because i do not show my code. :)

Comment: "variableA=hello" is a literal.  It contains no variables.  Is echo "variableA=hello" actually the code you are writing?  If it is not, why are you not pasting the exact code you are using??

Comment: sorry for the lack info,the post is edited.

Comment: Can we see you _actual_ PHP files? I don't see any opening `<?php` strings, so what you've posted is not what you are actually running. (If these are large, put them on an external Pastie or something).

Comment: If you could also improve your description, that would be helpful: "when i add some funny thing on the left hand side" doesn't give us much to go on, unfortunately.

Comment: Is it a 0x20 which is in font of your output?

Comment: Oh, sorry, i suppose it is understandable. Will trying hard to improve the post quality in the future. As this is only 4-5 post of mine.

Comment: when i look at the string in Flash, it show %20, which is space.

Comment: Then you **definitely** have a space somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce mentioned behaviour. Perhaps you need make sure that there is no space before the `<?php` and that there is no UTF BOM.

Comment: There must be anything. Whitespaces do not appear from nowhere.

Comment: this is what im doubt on. i check my script, and i found no extra whitespace. Even i assigned the string into new variable, and echo the variable out, it shows the same result.